# Lockout Duration in Weblogic does not work

Tags: weblogic

I set up Lockout Duration is 2mins, Lockout Threshold is 2. After 3 invalid login attemps, user 'abc' was locked automatically by weblogic.
But after 2mins, I try to login again, weblogic warns me that 'abc' still locked.
So anyone know what problem here is?

Comment: So just to be clear you went to `Security Realms->Configuration->user Lockout` and set the Duration? Did you also set the Reset Duration? Did you cycle the admin server after making the change? You should also see log messages in your admin server about lockout that may provide some hints

Comment: I set Reset Duration 5mins, is it ok?